# Expect Array of true values to be true

Tags: typescript, gulp-protractor

I have a function which is checking to see if all the elements which are supposed to be on a page are in fact on the page.

```
 /**
 * Elements are Displayed
 */
elementsDisplayed() {

    let elements = [
        this.emailTextField,
        this.pwordTextField,
        this.signInBtn,
        this.forgotLink,
    ];

    let elementsDisplayed = elements.map(function(element) {
        return element.isDisplayed();
    });

    let bundledPromise =  protractor.promise.all(elementsDisplayed)
    return bundledPromise
}
```

When I call this function it is returning an array of four true values. Right now I am calling this function and expecting it `.toEqual([true, true, true, true])`

Is there a way to either verify that each item in the array is `.toBe(true)`? I have tried the following and it fails. The function I have to check it is:

```
describe('Login Tests', () => {

it('Validate Login Page Elements', () => {
    let elementsVisible = loginPage.elementsDisplayed();
    _.forEach(elementsVisible, function(value) {
        expect(value).toBe(true);
    })
  });
});
```

The output is checking way more than 4 items; it is a whole bunch of `expected null to be true`, `expected undefined to be true`, `expected 'pending' to be true`, etc.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how we fixed it, we changed the `elementsDisplayed` method to look like this:

```
 /**
 * Elements are Displayed
 */
elementsDisplayed() {

    let elements = [
        this.emailTextField,
        this.pwordTextField,
        this.signInBtn,
        this.forgotLink,
    ];

    let elementsDisplayed = elements.map(function(element) {
        return element.isDisplayed();
    });

    return protractor.promise.all(elementsDisplayed).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        return _.every(result)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
let elementsVisible = loginPage.elementsDisplayed();
```

assigns a promise returned from `elementsDisplayes()` to `elementsVisible`

and this

```
_.forEach(elementsVisible ...
```

enumerates properties of that promise.

To get at the value of the promise, you have to use `then`

```
loginPage.elementsDisplayed().then(elementsVisible => {
    _.forEach(elementsVisible, function(value) {
        expect(value).toBe(true);
    })
})
```

but then your test somehow needs to be aware that `expect` is called in an asynchronous callback - I have no idea how to do async tests in protractor, sorry.